# ASP.net Schedule Post like Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

Im trying to do something similar to the Scheduling of posts for Facebook pages... on ASP.net/c#

So basically what i need is :

- User fills a few text boxes
- Selects a date...

The post gets posted on that date... 
I am unable to really understand the logic as well as coding for this...

What i have thought so far is, once the user submits the post, store the details in a table in SQL like SheduledPosts, and when the CurrentDate(Server Date) matches the date.... 
Transfer the SQL entry from there to the actual PostTable.

Now the actual process needs to take place without any pages loading or any actions done by the user... So I also dont understand how to make it happen from the server side...

Please note that im not trying to post anything to facebook... rather, trying to do a schedule form submitting on my own asp.net website...

Any help regarding the logic, coding, scheduling will be greatly appriciated...

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of different ways to accomplish this:

1. Implement a "pending posts" table and have a separate process running on the server to take care of transferring the post from the "pending posts" table to the "current posts" table at the appropriate time.
2. Add a "publish_on" datetime field to your current posts table, and when selecting items to be displayed in the page output, add a "WHERE publish_on IS NULL OR publish_on > GETDATE()" clause to your query.  You fill this in for posts you don't want going live until a particular time.

Personally, I would go with the second approach, since I think it's a more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree with approach 2.  You could even make it a window if so desired in that solution.  Just make sure the value stored for the publish date is irrespective of time zone or is stored with an offset, so the post doesn't inadvertently go live early/late depending on the viewer's time zone.  The approach in solution 2 also keeps the integrity of the post schema intact and removes the maintenance associated with essentially maintaining a second copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one table. Just have a 'Submitted' date field (for your records), a 'Publish' date field and a Boolean 'Published' field. Create a Windows Service to run every 5 minutes or so and let the service perform the date check; when it finds one that satisfies the date criteria, it just toggles the Boolean field to 'true' and your page logic can then display the post.

Here is a walk-through on creating a simple Windows Service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396